# jquery 2.1.4 toggle issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

i was using Jquery 1.7 in my project. So recently i upgraded to jquery 2.1.4.

The below code is not working now but earlier with older version it was working. Toggle is supported in 2.1.4 then please let me know what is wrong in the below code.

```
 jQuery('#show-hide-filter-text').toggle(function(){
            jQuery(this).text(hideTxt);
            jQuery('#filterListDiv').slideDown("medium");
        }, function(){
            jQuery(this).text(showTxt);
            jQuery('#filterListDiv').slideUp("medium");
        });
```

Comment: Can you provide the full code with HTML so we can see it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the toggle() method you are using is part of the event handling suite, and this was deprecated in version 1.8.
You could instead use the toggle() method that is part of the effects suite. The difference lies in the set of arguments that are passed.

Answer (score 1):

That form of `toggle` was [removed in jQuery 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/). You replace it with a simple `click` handler:

```
jQuery('#show-hide-filter-text').on("click", function() {
    var $this = jQuery(this),
        toggled = !!$this.data("toggled");
    if (toggled) {
        $this.text(showTxt);
        jQuery('#filterListDiv').slideUp("medium");
    } else {
        $this.text(hideTxt);
        jQuery('#filterListDiv').slideDown("medium");
    }
    $this.data("toggled", !toggled);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), the `toggle` method is generally called with a duration argument and a callback function (not 2 functions as you were providing).

A working alternative could be similar to the following

```
var hidden = false;
jQuery('#show-hide-filter-text').toggle(
  "medium", 
  function() {
    if (!hidden) {
      jQuery(this).text(hideTxt);
      jQuery('#filterListDiv').slideDown("medium");
    } else {
      jQuery(this).text(showTxt);
      jQuery('#filterListDiv').slideUp("medium");
    }
  }
);
```